# How to implement Serde Deserializer for wire protocol with multiple representations of strings?

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to implement a Serde `Serializer`/`Deserializer` for the [Kafka wire protocol](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html). In this protocol, there are 4 different string representations. This poses a problem when implementing the deserializer: when `deserialize_str` is called to attempt to deserialize a string for a given message, there’s no way to know whether a string starts with `i32` or a `varint`, since neither the `deserialize_str` method or the provided visitor provides any kind of metadata or type information that could be used to help make this decision.

My first thought was that I could implement a new type wrapper and use a custom deserialize implementation, but I now understand this doesn’t make sense because it needs to be generic over *all* deserializers, not just the deserializer I’m building. The wrapper still just asks the `Deserializer` to read a string.

I’m struggling to come up with a good solution here, and can’t find examples of other data formats that use multiple representations for a given data type.

Comment: Seems to be a discussion based personal opinion question, you have to be bit more specific, and provide code examples on how you want it to behave

Answer (score 0):

Here's the EXTREMELY HACKY way that I'm planning on solving this using a new type wrapper and custom `Deserialize` implementation. More specifically, my `Deserialize` impl will have it's own `Visitor` and we're going abuse `Visitor` here.

First I was hoping that I could use `TypeId` on `Visitor::Value`, but `Visitor` doesn't have a static lifetime, so that doesn't work.

Instead, I'm using the "expected" error message as a type tag, using the `serde::de::Expected` trait:

```rust
 fn deserialize_str<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value>
        where
            V: Visitor<'de>,
    {
        use serde::de::Expected;
        let ty = format!("{}", &visitor as &dyn Expected);
        if ty == "NullableString" {
          // ... do nullable dstring deserialization logic here
        }
      // ...
    }
```

This... works! But feels extremely gross. Not totally satisfied, but goign to proceed with this for now.